# Chrome or Chromium retry corrupted/incomplete download file functionality

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium, plugins

Is there any functionality available in Chrome or Chromium browser mentioned below:

- Retry corrupted/incomplete download (from the time it is left)

Sometimes because of network failure/disconnection problem, the download becomes incomplete. But in Mozilla Firefox we can continue download from the point it is left.

This is native feature available in Mozilla Firefox, is this available for Chrome/Chromium browser?

Or do we need external plug-in for downloading files to get these functionality?

Comment: Isn't (n) where `n` increments each time you download the same file just appended to the filename if you redownload something with Chrome/Chromium?

Comment: That'ts true, I was unable to explain my problem exactly, edited with same now.

Comment: Okay. AFAIK, the resume download feature is missing from Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: There are slightly complicated workarounds using `wget`, for example. See http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/resume-interrupted-download-chrome and google for "google chrome resume download".